# Selecting an item in an HTML SELECT list using keyboard doesnt trigger the CLICK event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, selectlist

I have an HTML select list which, when an item is selected, must show different information beneath it. The onclick or JQuery change events are triggered when a select list item is selected by being clicked on (mouse), but not when the user uses key presses (keyboard).

Any idea what event to watch in order to determine when the selected list item has changed?

Here is a BASIC test example:

```
<select id="mylist" name="mylist">
    <option value="">(none)</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<span id="myspan"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mylist").change(function() {
        $("#myspan").html($("#mylist").attr("selectedIndex"));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You aren't listening on the `click` event. You're listening on the `change` event. Update title accordingly :)

Comment: In @BalusC's defense, `click` and `change` are not the same.  `change` fires only if the selection changes -- clicking on an already selected option wouldn't fire it.  Also, why would using the keyboard to change the option fire a `click` event?  If anything is folly, it is not summarising your question appropriately in the title.  Finally, why would changing a select element with a keyboard trigger a `click` event?  That doesn't make much sense, my dear ;-)

Comment: Wow, what an attitude. Do I have a new fan?

Comment: Andy, logically, who would want the information in the `span` to change if the option that was already selected was clicked again? If you test the test example above, you will see that both `onclick` and `onchange` are handled by the jquery handler.

Comment: @Jimbo: I don't understand how you think that's relevant - maybe you missed my point.  And FYI, if both `onclick` and `onchange` were handled by your `change` handler, the function would fire twice.  Instead, the `change` event precedes the `click` event and only the `change` event is handled.

Comment: For the unaware: Jimbo deleted a comment wherein he said *The JQuery 'change' event is triggered with onclick as well. Letting your pedantry display your lack of knowledge is folly my dear.* Hence my somewhat astonishing comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will run when the `select` box loses focus
(*press tab or click anywhere outside of the `select` box*)

Answer (score 1):

The OnChange event is different from browser to browser when an item is changed with keyboard shortcuts.

For example, in IE, the event is fired the same way with the keyboard and the mouse, but in Firefox, to trigger the event with the keyboard, you need to press *enter* when the item selected is the good one. The event is also fired when the <select> loose focus (OnBlur - and only if OnChange has not already been fired) as Gaby pointed out.

It the way it's made...

Comment: Pressing enter to confirm a `<select>` element choice is a bad idea, it may submit a parent form as well as firing the `onchange` event.

Comment: Unless you use a third world class Web browser or if the focus is NOT on the <select>, using enter is perfectly safe to confirm selection on a <select>. How do you think disabled people trigger onchange? By tabbing out and alt-tabbing back each time? Read WCAG or S508 guidelines for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you change add attribute:

```
multiple="multiple"
```

if you want the dropbox, I'd bind a 'global' keyup event handler to the document.body
and do some magic there.